# Umbraco 5 ask if user has permission to node

Tags: umbraco

Im working with Umbraco 5.1 beta. On the internet  (this information is from previous versions, could not find recent documentation on it) I find that I could ask a node if the user has Access. In that way I want to build up my menu. The thing is, I cant get it to work, the HasAccess and IsProtected properties are not working. What am I doing wrong? Or does it work different in the newer versions of Umbraco? (I also tried it as method, still no result)

This is the code I'm now using:

```
@inherits RenderViewPage
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web;

 @{
     var Homepage = @DynamicModel;
     while (Homepage.ContentType.Alias != "homePage")
     {
         Homepage = Homepage.Parent;
     }
 }
  <ul>
      <li><a href="@Homepage.Url">Home</a></li>
  @foreach (var item in Homepage.Children) {
      if(!item.IsProtected || (item.IsProtected && item.HasAccess)) {
          if(@item.CurrentTemplate != null) {
              var childName = item.Name ?? "(No name yet)";
              <li><a href="@item.Url">@childName </a></li>
          }
      }
  }
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just looking to suppress nodes that the user cannot access. Then you can use the WhereCanAccess() method.

Example: (This will hide all child nodes that the user doesn't have access to)

```
@inherits RenderViewPage
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web;

 @{
     var Homepage = @DynamicModel;
     while (Homepage.ContentType.Alias != "homePage")
     {
         Homepage = Homepage.Parent;
     }
 }
  <ul>
      <li><a href="@Homepage.Url">Home</a></li>
      @foreach (var item in Homepage.Children.WhereCanAccess())
      {
          if(@item.CurrentTemplate != null)
          {
              var childName = item.Name ?? "(No name yet)";
              <li><a href="@item.Url">@childName </a></li>
          }
      }
  </ul>
```

Trying to find if a node IsProtected seems to be somewhat more complex (although only a couple of lines of code. Well the only way I found find to do it anyway!)

Example: (This just puts an * next to the name of protected menu items)

```
@inherits RenderViewPage
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web;

 @{
     var Homepage = @DynamicModel;
     while (Homepage.ContentType.Alias != "homePage")
     {
         Homepage = Homepage.Parent;
     }

     var appContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUmbracoApplicationContext>();
 }
  <ul>
  <li><a href="@Homepage.Url">Home</a></li>
  @foreach (var item in Homepage.Children)
  {
      var isProtected = appContext.Security.PublicAccess.IsProtected(item.Id);

      if (@item.CurrentTemplate != null)
      {
          var childName = item.Name ?? "(No name yet)";
          childName = (isProtected) ? "* " + childName : childName; 
          <li><a href="@item.Url">@childName </a></li>
      }
  }
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works. Now I only need to figure out how to build a login widget. I try to create a macro from the loginformtemplate that was in the default sollution, but it does not work. Do you maybe have a suggestion?

Comment: I know this question asks explicitly for Umbraco 5 but if you want to use this in Umbraco 7 use [MemberHasAccess](https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/reference/Querying/UmbracoHelper/#memberhasaccess-int-nodeid-string-path)