# Umbraco 7 hide navigation nodes user has no access to

Tags: razor, umbraco7

I've seen some examples in previous versions of Umbraco (namely 5) where this seemed to be relatively straightforward. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064231/umbraco-5-ask-if-user-has-permission-to-node) for example.

The theory is that I can use a property `HasAccess` or `IsProtected` on a node, or the method `WhereHasAccess` when selecting which nodes to use.

The code I have so far is:

```
var nodes = @CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf(1).First().Children;
```

This gets me the list of pages, no problem. However, I am struggling to filter the list of pages so that a logged in user only sees what they have access to and a public visitor sees no protected pages.

The V5 code suggests this is possible:

`var nodes = @CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf(1).First().Children.WhereCanAccess();`

But this results in the error:

`'Umbraco.Web.Models.DynamicPublishedContentList' does not contain a definition for 'WhereCanAccess'`

The latest published version of the [Razor cheatsheet for Umbraco](http://our.umbraco.org/FileDownload?id=8865) indicates that `HasAccess()` and `IsProtected()` are two methods that are both available, but when using either of these I get null values, e.g.:

```
@foreach(var node in nodes.WhereCanAccess()) {
    <li>@node.Name / @node.IsProtected / @node.IsProtected() / @node.HasAccess() / @node.HasAccess </li>
}
```

Returns null for all the test values (e.g. `@node.IsProtected`).

It seems that what I am trying to achieve is simple, but I am approaching it the wrong way. Someone please point out the error of my ways!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I check user access to pages like this:

```
var node = [the page you want to verify access to ie. "CurrentPage"];
var isProtected = umbraco.library.IsProtected(node.id, node.path);
var hasAccess = umbraco.library.HasAccess(item.id, item.path);
```

My top menu code:

```
   var homePage = CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf(1).First();
    var menuItems = homePage.Children.Where("UmbracoNaviHide == false");
    @foreach (var item in menuItems)
    {
        var loginAcces = umbraco.library.IsProtected(item.id, item.path) && umbraco.library.HasAccess(item.id, item.path);
        var cssClass = loginAcces ? "loginAcces ":"";
        cssClass += CurrentPage.IsDescendantOrSelf(item) ? "current_page_item" :"";                           

        if(!umbraco.library.IsProtected(item.id, item.path) || loginAcces){
            [render your item here]
        }
}
```

This will hide items that are protected, unless user is logged in and has access.

Comment: This was exactly it - I was clearly getting the syntax wrong. Rather than `item.HasAccess()` the call is `umbraco.library.HasAccess(item.id, item.path)`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Thank to @user3815602 I did it like this

Created one extension method

```
namespace CPalm.Core
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {

        public static bool CurrentUserHasAccess(this IPublishedContent content)
        {
            int contentId = content.Id;
            string contentPath = content.Path;

            bool isProtected = umbraco.library.IsProtected(contentId, contentPath);
            if (isProtected)
            {
                bool hasAccess = umbraco.library.HasAccess(contentId, contentPath);
                if (!hasAccess)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And can be used like this

```
foreach (IPublishedContent content in CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf(1).First().Children)
{
    if (!content.CurrentUserHasAccess())
        continue;

    /* The current user has access to the content */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have here an other way to achive it.

`Model.Content.Children.Where(o => Umbraco.IsProtected(o.Id, o.Path)).Any()`